# London rail and tube station locations

Tags: data-request, geospatial, uk, public-transport

I'm looking for a data set of rail and tube stations in the Transport for London network, specifically, stations where one could use an Oyster card.

I'm interested in the locations of these stations so the data should either include coordinates or addresses/postcodes that I can geocode.

It doesn't matter if the data includes stations outside London, as long as I can accurately match a station in London to the entry in the data set based on its name.

The KML file offered by TfL and described [here](https://www.tfl.gov.uk/info-for/open-data-users/our-feeds?intcmp=3671) doesn't include National Rail or Overground stations, despite promising otherwise.

Answer (score 7):

Alex, I looked through the TFL APIs, documentation and datasets. The station list (KML) format indicates it has locations for light rail (DLR), tube and overground. But as you observed there are no entries for overground stations. I also did not find anything on National Rail in the documentation.

I did find some additional resources. Below is the National Rail's list of stations in London (which you would need to scrape):

http://www.nationalrail.co.uk/css/OfficialNationalRailmaplarge.pdf

The Guardian maintains its own downloadable dataset of all rail stations in Great Britian. .

http://www.theguardian.com/news/datablog/2011/may/19/train-stations-listed-rail#data
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AonYZs4MzlZbcktheEZFeF84U1J4dFFvckI5X0VBcEE#gid=7

It appears the Guardian reversed engineered the dataset from the Office of Rail Regulation' station usage statistics.

http://orr.gov.uk/statistics/published-stats/station-usage-estimates

The UK data.gov has a dataset labeled: National Public Transport Access nodes (NAPTAN).

> NaPTAN is a GB national system for uniquely identifying all the points
>   of access to public transport in GB. It is a core component of the GB
>   national transport information infrastructure and is used by a number
>   of other UK standards and information systems. Every GB station, coach
>   terminus, airport, ferry terminal, bus stop, etc., is allocated at
>   least one identifier.

http://data.gov.uk/dataset/naptan

Answer (score 2):

A more up to date resource is the Transport for London Unified API. For example you can get a list of all the tube stops like so:

https://api.tfl.gov.uk/StopPoint/Mode/tube

You can find out more about the Unified API by reading the [blog articles](http://blog.tfl.gov.uk/2015/10/08/unified-api-part-2-lot-location-of-things/) Dan and I have written.