# Publicly Available UK Datasets

Tags: uk, data-portal

With no disrespect to our fellow data scientists over "the pond", one major problem from the rest of the world's point of view with questions like [Publicly Available Datasets](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/155/publicly-available-datasets) is the American focus of the answers. They are great answers, and great sources of data, but lack a lot relevance to others not in the US due to geographic, demographic, social or other factors.

This question I have is particularly focused on **public data** sites for the **UK**.

Are there sites that have a large variety of data collected? I suspect at the moment the UK isn't as progressive as the USA in terms of meta-data repositories, so I would be happy for sites that are quite rich in content and interesting in terms of their data science or analytical possibilities!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try https://geovation.uk/data-sources/ for a pretty comprehensive list of links to sources with crime data, retail data, consumer data, transport data and government data.

You can also refer to [this list](http://www.opendatanottingham.org.uk/other-providers.aspx) to fill in the gaps on English Heritage data, environment data and Ordnance Survey data.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 7):

In Scotland specifically, I would suggest that you have a look at:

- [**Statistics.gov.scot**](http://statistics.gov.scot/) - a very decent repository of publicly available data in Scotland, a lot of spatially aggregated.

## UK

- [**NOMIS**](https://www.nomisweb.co.uk/Default.asp) - spatially aggregated labour market data
- [**UK Data Service**](https://discover.ukdataservice.ac.uk/) - vast catalogue of research / survey data
- [**Neigbhourhood Statistics**](http://www.neighbourhood.statistics.gov.uk) - ONS product with neighbourhood statistics.

Answer (score 4):

Just to add, Northern Ireland now has its own Open Data Portal: https://www.opendatani.gov.uk/

Answer (score 3):

The UK has an open data portal: **https://data.gov.uk/**

London has one of the most comprehensive open data portals: **http://data.london.gov.uk/**

Additionally, you'll find regions and cities have their own open data portals: for example: http://open.manchester.gov.uk/

There is the [uk](/questions/tagged/uk) tag [on this site](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uk?sort=votes&pageSize=50) which brings up 25 questions. In particular, the [Q&A about London Tube locations](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/4027/1511) has a nice resource.

For an overview of open data in the UK - check out the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Data_in_the_United_Kingdom).

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The Royal Economic Society has a list of data links:
http://www.res.org.uk/view/dataResources.html

The American Economic Association lists the [Bank of England](http://www.BankofEngland.co.uk/), [HM Treasury](http://www.hm-treasury.gov.uk/), and [National Statistics](http://www.statistics.gov.uk/)

In the ReplicationWiki (that I work on) you can see [data sources](http://replication.uni-goettingen.de/wiki/index.php/Category:Article_data_source) used for publications in economic journals [here](http://replication.uni-goettingen.de/wiki/index.php?title=Special%3AAsk&q=%5B%5BArticle+origin+of+data+used%3A%3AUK%5D%5D&po=%3FArticle+data%0D%0A%3FArticle+program+code%0D%0A%3FArticle+data+used%0D%0A%3FArticlejel%0D%0A%3FArticlekeywords%0D%0A%3FArticle+software+used%0D%0A%3FArticle+methods+and+estimation%0D%0A%3FArticle+data+used%0D%0A%3FArticle+origin+of+data+used%0D%0A%3FReplication+type%0D%0A%3FReplication+result%0D%0A%3FReplication+raw+data%0D%0A%3FReplication+call+into+question%0D%0A%3FReplication+authors+statement%0D%0A&eq=yes&p%5Bformat%5D=broadtable&sort_num=&order_num=ASC&p%5Blimit%5D=250&p%5Boffset%5D=&p%5Blink%5D=all&p%5Bsort%5D=&p%5Bheaders%5D=show&p%5Bmainlabel%5D=&p%5Bintro%5D=&p%5Boutro%5D=&p%5Bsearchlabel%5D=%E2%80%A6+further+results&p%5Bdefault%5D=&p%5Bclass%5D=sortable+wikitable+smwtable&eq=yes)

Answer (score 3):

Some interesting UK sites with data not yet mentioned are:

The [Health and Social Care Information Centre](http://www.hscic.gov.uk) (soon to be renamed NHS Digital) which make a wide range of health-related data available on various terms. data can sometimes be hard to find but there is a lot there including vast quantities of data about England's NHS (e.g. everything prescribed by each GP practice every month, vast quantities of different indicators about health outcomes and population health).

[The Land Registry](https://www.gov.uk/government/organisations/land-registry). They have a dataset of all property transactions since about 1995 (i.e. the record of prices paid for domestic housing) which is fascinating.

[The Office for National Statistics](https://www.ons.gov.uk) has a lot of data but has a reputation for being fabulously difficult to navigate (but is getting better).